# How to extract json data to different string?

Tags: android, json, string

Hi I am new in android app development.I had created an app which fetch data from json.I used the following code

```
            JSONArray jArray2 = new JSONArray(res);


              for(int i=0;i<jArray2.length();i++){


                JSONObject json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);

                String   img=json_data2.getString("image");

                 }
```

my json contains 5 strings with tag "image".How can I extracted into diff string value ??

Comment: what is the problem you are facing while doing so, you can either use a `ArrayList` of Strings to get all the urls

Comment: Create a array instead.

Comment: @David: please help me with some code

Comment: crate List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();  images.add(img);

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
JSONArray jArray2 = new JSONArray(res);

        String imgArray[] = new String[jArray2.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray2.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);

            imgArray[i] = json_data2.getString("image");
            Log.d("Image Names", "image is " + imgArray[i]);
        }
```

// To get Images

```
    String image1 = imgArray[0];
    String image2 = imgArray[1];
    String image3 = imgArray[2];
    String image4 = imgArray[3];
    String image5 = imgArray[4];
```

**USING ARRAYLIST**

```
JSONArray jArray2 = new JSONArray(res);

        ArrayList<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray2.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);

            imageList.add(json_data2.getString("image"));

        }

        String image1 = imageList.get(0);
        String image2 = imageList.get(1);
        String image3 = imageList.get(2);
        String image4 = imageList.get(3);
        String image5 = imageList.get(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray2.length();i++){
JSONObject json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);
if(i==0)
{
 String image = json_data2.getString("image");
}
else if(i==1)
{
 String image1 = json_data2.getString("image");
}
else if(i==2)
{
 String image2 = json_data2.getString("image");
}
else if(i==3)
{
 String image3 = json_data2.getString("image");
}
else if(i==4)
{
 String image4 = json_data2.getString("image");
}
}
```